# DataList, Conditional statements in <ItemTemplate>?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am trying to do the following in ASP.NET 3.5.  Basically, I am binding a LINQDataSource to a DataList.  There is a property called "Deleted" and if it is true, I want to display different markup.  The following code throws errors:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% If CBool(Eval("Deleted")) Then%> 
            ...
        <% Else%>
            ...
        <% End If%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Is this possible?  If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: you should really look into @Aydsman's solution, it's superior to the accepted answer when you have multiple controls in your <ItemTemplate>

Comment: @roman Thanks, both are great answers. But I think I prefer RandomNoob's solution to use the RowDataBound event since Eval can be avoided altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the RowDataBound event and check the value of your fields then? RowDatabound is ideal for these situations where you want to alter data in a gridview based on values in the result set.

[RowDataBound Event from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Comment: An answer should start with a yes or no and explanation. And then possibly provide alternatives. To answer your question "why?" -"Because I don't to mix back-end code with UI logic. Because I want UI logic in the markup and not in the back-end code."

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan this was answered in 2008. Again 2008. Let that sink in for a while.

Answer (score 11):

I might suggest keeping the code-front lean and writing out the desired text via a function result:

```
<asp:DataList runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <%# GetText(Container.DataItem) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And the code-behind:

```
protected static string GetText(object dataItem)
{        
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(dataItem, "Deleted"))
        return "Deleted";

    return "Not Deleted";
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks a bunch for this. It is spot on and helpful.

Answer (score 5):

One option as a work-around would be to utilise a panel.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel Visible="<%# Eval("Deleted") %>">
            ...(deleted content here)...
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel Visible="<%# Not Eval("Deleted") %>">
            ...(other content here)...
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Best solution!!! To get around the "The server tag is not well formed" error change outer quotation marks from double quote to single quote like this: Visible='<%# Eval("Deleted") %>'

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the ItemDataBound event of a datalist. For gridview's its the rowdatabound event that is ideal for altering display of values based on other values in the result set.
[ItemDataBound event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx)

So basically on itemdatabound you can play around with your conditionals. Again, this is an educated guess since I've typically done this with the RowDataBound event on gridview's.

Comment: I agree with the educated guess, and the link to the ItemDataBound event does a good job of explaining it.  

Ben Griswold's route will also work; However, I find it a little cleaner and more flexible to hook into the DataList's ItemDataBound event as mentioned.