# How to show 4 photo on slider?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I would like to show 4 photo on all each slider but i can get only 1 photo 
[image: look at this slider screenshot please]

Is there any different way to show 4 photos side by side on slider?

[image: i want like this]

```
 <div class='slider'>
                        <ul class='slides'>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rpShowcaseAlbum" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                               <li>
                                <!-- Showcase Album -->
                                <div class='span12'>
                                        <a href="album_detay.aspx?ArtistID=<%#Eval("ArtistID") %>">
                                            <div class="photo_frame">
                                                <img src='Admin/uploads/photo/<%#Eval("Photo") %>' style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 250px;" alt='' />
                                                <div class='text'>
                                                    <span class='artist'><%#Eval("ArtistName") %></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                       </ul>
                    </div>


  if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            rpShowcaseAlbum.DataSource = Dt;
            rpShowcaseAlbum.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Which slider script did you use?

Comment: In Wpf, I usually put all on a `stack` or like a `panel`, which make it very easy

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating wrapping li and div for each item in the slider. You can use item index to render these li and div only when needed:

```
<%# Container.ItemIndex % 4 == 0 ? "<li><div class='span12'>" : "" %>

    <a href="album_detay.aspx?ArtistID=<%#Eval("ArtistID") %>">
        <div class="photo_frame">
            <img src='Admin/uploads/photo/<%#Eval("Photo") %>' style="max-width: 250px; max-height: 250px;" alt='' />
            <div class='text'>
                <span class='artist'><%#Eval("ArtistName") %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>

<%# Container.ItemIndex % 4 == 3 ? "</div></li>" : "" %>
```

This is a bit of a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168958/728795), and is done because of the fact that Container is actually available in data binding context only.

Comment: i got error: `The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @Shqiptar, yeah, sorry, just realized Container is actually available in data binding context only. Updated with a bit trickier way